# Where is "pin to source" in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I can't find the "**Pin to Source**" functionality in Visual Studio 2017, was it removed?

I Googled it and nothing til now.

Comment: It was not removed, works fine.  Ensure the debugger is in break mode.  Hover over the variable until the datatip pops up, click the pin.  Spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune if that doesn't work.

Comment: As you can see in this image, there is no "Pin to Source" for me:

[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/1743/PHtmrm.png)

Comment: I agree, they just removed the toolbars and keyboard shortcuts. it still works, just can't create a keyboard shortcut. ooof

Answer (score 5):

This option is also missing for me in VS 2017.  I am however able to pin variables by hovering over the variable and clicking the pin icon on the far right of the tooltip that pops up.  This accomplishes the same thing for now.

Comment: Sure, but, must use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VS2019. I tried importing a backup setting from prior year (Tool > Import and Export), and turns out my old hotkey for this command still works -- even though I still can't see the Pin To Source in the hotkey mapping window. You can try this work around.